# Javascript ajax code is not working in ibm worklight?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating a hybrid app using IBM Worklight.I use the following code to fetch XML data from server using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                 (function ($) {
            /**
             * Constructor method that sets up a CORS hack
             * and makes the ajax request
             */
            function _construct() {
                // jquery cors hack to enable cross-domain loading
                // see: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/
                $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
                if (options.crossDomain && $.support.cors) {
                    options.url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
                }
                });

                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                url: 'http://newsyogi.com/xml/india.xml',
                error: function (textStatus, error) {
                    $('body').text('Error fetching feed :/');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // this is the hack, it makes xml a breeze, simply 
                    // convert the xml data to a jquery object
                    var xmlJqueryObject = $(data);
                    render(xmlJqueryObject);
                }
                });

            }

            /**
             * Parses the xml then 
             */
            function render(feed) {
                var list = [];
                // we can use jquery selectors to pick the data
                // and choose the data we need


                feed.find('feed').each(function (i, item) {             

                // seems familiar...
                var $book = $(this); 
                       var title = $book.find('title').text();
                       var description = $book.find('description').text();
                    var imageurl = $book.find('sort').text();                       
                    var dateTime= $book.find('news').text();

                    if (imageurl == ""  ) {
                       imageurl='<img title="Be Transparent While Dealing With US: Congress to Government" alt="Be Transparent While Dealing With US: Congress to Government" id="story_image_main" src="http://www.ndtv.com/news/images/story_page/US_President_Obama_with_PM_Modi_White_House_650.jpg">';

                    }
                    $("#newsContent_area").append(
                    '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb "><div class="panel panel-default flex-col""><div class="panel-heading">  <div class="image_categories"> <h4 class="news-title">'+title+'</h4><img class="news_images img-responsive" src="'
                    + imageurl +'"</div></div>  </div><div class="panel-body flex-grow newscontent"><div class="news_caption"> <span class="news_categories "><a>'+description+'</a></span></div></div></div></div>');
                    });
            }

            //call the constructor
            _construct();

               })(jQuery);

</script>
```

It fetches and shows data in browser side.But while converting the app to iOS and run as a xcode project it shows following error.(Error fetching data.)
How to solve it (or) any other alternate solutions to solve it.

Comment: You're not showing the error you get in the Xcode console.

Comment: One solution: use Worklight adapters instead.

Comment: @IdanAdar XCode doesn't show any error in console.It shows just loading of respective .html file. Using worklight adapters is the only way to parse xml data (OR)  whether there is any alternate way to parse XML data from Server.

Comment: Adapters also allow you to use XSL Transformation on the resulting data before it arrives to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapters provide you with the flexibility to connect to any backend system type. You can also utilize Worklight's security framework to protect access to these backend systems if required.

For your issue, adapters also provide a means to use XSL Transformation on the response from the backend before it reaches back to the client application that originally sent the request for the data.

You can [read more](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/) about it:

- [Adapters Overview](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/)
- [HTTP JavaScript adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/js-http-adapter/)
- [Invoking adapters in Hybrid applications](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/)